# Как обнулить ховеры для планшетов и мобилок?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Я знаю что для планшетов и мобилок нужно все классы с hover обнулить. Но я незнаю как будет правильне и что чаще используют.
Я думал все ховеры поместить в медиавыражение @media handheld или сразу написать @media(min-width="1024px") и в нем писать ховеры.
И еще, focus тоже надо убирать для планшетов и мобилок или нет?

Comment: Что значит «обнулить ховеры» и зачем их «обнулять» вообще?

Comment: Видимо автор говорит о том, что на мобилках и планшетах ведь нет курсоров, следовательно, :hover там не нужен. Сам не понимаю зачем это, но раз решили, то у Вас медиа запрос написан не правильно, вот так надо - @media (max-width: 1024px). Вообще я ни разу не встречал такое. И :focus я бы оставил, так как при заполнении форм у Вас поля в фокусе.

Comment: @SLideR11 однако на мобилках и планшетах есть touchstart, от которых :hover вполне срабатывает, поэтому я думаю, что он скорее всего всё-таки нужен